# php remove the links and content

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

Hi all I've a little php question:

I've a many strings like that:

```
$content = "Hi I am a <a href='http://blabla' ...>black</a> cat";
```

How can i convert this string to:

```
$content = "Hi I am a cat";
```

I tried that but doesn't works...

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/","$1",$content);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks just about right.

I just tried this and it seemed to work fine:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/","",$content);
```

Comment: Hi, I dont want to get : Hi I am a black cat so i want to get: Hi I am a cat

Answer (score 1):

[No use REGEX!!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) Use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
echo strip_tags( "Hi I am a <a href='http://blabla' ...> black</a> cat" );
// Hi I am a  black cat 
// (there will be a double space there because a space comes before and after
// the opening for the <a> tag. You can use str_replace('  ', ' ', $val) to get
// rid of all double spaces/
```

If you are simply trying to get rid of the "black" as well, you might want to try DomDocument:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadXML( "<root>" . // you'll need a root.
       "Hi I am a <a href='http://blabla' ...> black</a> cat".
"</root>");
$nodes = array();
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item )
{
   $nodes[]=$item;
}
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
   if( $node->parentNode ) $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $doc->documentElement->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Hi, I dont want to get :

Hi I am a  black cat

so i want to get:

Hi I am a cat

Comment: nothing get by: echo $doc->documentElement->firstChild->nodeValue;

Comment: Ah. It was parentNode, not parentElement.