# Swapping an <a> for <span> using PHP

Tags: php, strip-tags

**Please can someone help me edit my question so it complies with SO rules? I have asked a valid question and received the answer from a helpful SO'er yet it hasn't been well received by the SO community**

I am pulling a block of code through, stripping out the unnecessary code then using the remaining code in my page.

The code contains anchor tags who's links I do not wish to keep but I need to be able to leave styling on the link elements.

I currently use

```
$tweettext = strip_tags($tweettext, '<div>, <p>, <a>');
```

Which works. But, leaves me with anchor tags that link to broken links (they are broken as it uses relative linking and is pulled from an external website).

If I use

```
$tweettext = strip_tags($tweettext, '<div>, <p>');
```

It removes the unneccessary links but I now don't have an element I can apply styles to.

Am I able to swap the tag from an 'a' tag to a 'span' tag before running it through to strip unnecessary tags ('a' isn't needed once the 'a's text is wrapped in the 'span')?

So I can use

```
$tweettext = strip_tags($tweettext, '<div>, <p>, <span>');
```

I just need a straight swap 'a' to 'span' function.

**CODE PON DE REQUEST (not that relevant to my actual question, I simply wish to know the function where I can swap_tags() or swap_text()):**

**Working Code (making use of the preg_match(), the answer to my question):**

```
<?php
foreach($tweet->find('.tweet-text') as $tweettext) {
    $tweettext = str_ireplace('TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text ', '', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = str_ireplace('data-aria-label-part="0"', '', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = str_ireplace('lang="en" ', '', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = str_ireplace('data-query-source="hashtag_click" ', '', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = str_ireplace(' pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" ', '"', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = preg_replace('/href=".*?"/', '', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = str_ireplace('<a', '<span', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = str_ireplace('</a>', '</span>', $tweettext);
    $tweettext = strip_tags($tweettext, '<div>, <p>, <span>');
    if($imgmatches[1] != '') {
        $tweettext = str_ireplace('tweet-text', 'tweet-text tweet-has-bg-text ', $tweettext);
    } else {
        $tweettext = str_ireplace('tweet-text', 'tweet-text', $tweettext);
    }
    echo $tweettext;
}
```

**Correct Output:**

```
<p class="tweet-text">
    We’ve got a number of international exhibition stand builds this quarter; including <span class="twitter-atreply" data-mentioned-user-id="441777148">@StocExpo</span> in Rotterdam. This is the 4th year we have undertaken a stand at StocExpo for <span class="twitter-atreply" data-mentioned-user-id="290202396">@Dantecltd</span> <span class="twitter-hashtag">#exhibition</span> <span class="twitter-hashtag">#StocExpo</span>
</p>
```

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: show us the value of `$tweettext`

Comment: [According the the example, there are no space or commas between the allowed tags.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#refsect1-function.strip-tags-examples)

Comment: Please share some input data that makes your problem reproducable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084565/php-remove-the-links-and-content might help

Comment: @window.document - ding ding ding - you're my man. Thanks for the correct answer. Feel free to post an answer that I can allocate the win to.

Comment: Because my question was actually beautifully worded with sufficient information to get the answer to my question. Please can you cancel your downvotes. I rely a lot on sharing information and really appreciate being able to use this community.

Comment: Don't expect people to return once they've downvoted, and they are also under no obligation to do so. Glad you got some answers though!

Comment: That isn't very Stack Overflow P.C. is it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op doesn't need a `DOMDocument` object as mentioned by [RamRaider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342459/swapping-an-a-for-span-using-php/55343222#55343222)  rather a string which is used as the html which makes regex the best operation fitting in this case, the suitable regex expression for the following case turns out, is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084565/php-remove-the-links-and-content) 
 Which is also

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/","",$content);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `"swap_tags"` function to solve your problem but you could craft your own using `DOMDocument` rather than string replacement as above. The following ought to demonstrate how that might be accomplished. It loads the HTML string into the `DOMDocument` object and searches for all hyperlinks. When it has found the hyperlinks it will work backwards through the DOM tree to perform modifications ( if you were to iterate forwards it would stop after first mod )

The attributes from each encountered hyperlink are added to a newly created `SPAN` element  - you might wish to modify that or add a filter to exclude certain attributes ( `href` for instance )

```
<?php

    $str='<p class="tweet-text">
        We’ve got a number of international exhibition stand builds this quarter; including 
        <a href="/StocExpo" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" data-mentioned-user-id="441777148">@StocExpo</a>
        in Rotterdam. This is the 4th year we have undertaken a stand at StocExpo for 
        <a href="/Dantecltd" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" data-mentioned-user-id="290202396">@Dantecltd</a> 
        <a href="/hashtag/exhibition?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr">#exhibition</a> 
        <a href="/hashtag/StocExpo?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr">#StocExpo</a>
    </p>';

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->loadHTML( $str );
    libxml_clear_errors();


    $col = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    if( $col->length > 0 ){

        for( $i=$col->length; $i > 0; $i-- ){
            $node=$col->item( $i );

            if( !empty( $node ) && $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ){
                $span=$dom->createElement('span', $node->nodeValue );


                foreach( $node->attributes as $attr ){
                    $attribute=$dom->createAttribute( sprintf('data-%s',$attr->nodeName ) );
                    $attribute->nodeValue=$attr->nodeValue;
                    $span->appendChild( $attribute );
                }

                $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $span, $node );
            }
        }


        printf('<textarea cols=100 rows=20>%s</textarea>', $dom->saveHTML() );
    }

?>
```